# Button back "one level up" in form

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button "reset" that takes you to the beginning of form. What I shoud change for the button "back", which is backed by one level?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/bj8pd5op/31/)

```
$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $('#firstField');
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't have a previous button?

Comment: It`s only reset button takes to Begin of form.

Answer (score 1):

You're already storing the current slide when you click next...

```
current_fs = $(this).parent()
```

But the problem is that this variable is scoped to your next function which means you can't retrieve the value of `current_fs` when you want to go back. What you need to do is define this variable outside the next function, set it when you hit next, and then when you want to go back, pull the value.

For example...

```
var currentSlide;

$('.next').on('click', function(){
    currentSlide = $(this).parent();
    // go to next slide code
});

$('.prev').on('click', function(){
    // go back to currentSlide, which is actually the previous slide
});
```

Comment: What about: $(this).parent().prev() ?